# Android Google Maps load visible marker

Tags: android, google-maps

How to load just visible marker in screen on google maps?
I'm using method setOnCameraChangeListener but there's a bug. When i zoom maps and i move to another marker that was outside the screen, the marker is missing. The marker will visible when i zoom out or zoom in. Does anyone can help me?
Here's my code

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                ClusterManager<MyItem> myItemClusterManager = getmClusterManager();
                myItemClusterManager.clearItems();
                if(mMap!=null) {
                    LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                    for (MyItem item : visibleMarkers) {
                        if (bounds.contains(item.getPosition())) {
                            myItemClusterManager.addItem(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried reclustering after adding new items to your `myItemClusterManager`? Just do `myItemClusterManager.cluster()` after your `for` loop

Comment: it's work, thank a lot dude :)